# batch replace command, i'm confused

Tags: batch-file, replace

okay, so I tried this

```
set x=12 &
set var=(x)
set var=%var:(=^%%
set var=%var:)=^%%
echo %var%
```

and I get x%%

then I did this

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set var=!var:(=%!

set var=!var:)=%!

echo %var%
```

and I get !var:)=%!

both methods failed, so I need help.

Comment: What is the question ?

Comment: Help with what? _Explain your question!_

Comment: Sorry for not clarifying, I meant that I want var to equal %x%, like convert the '(' and ')' to '%'.

Answer (score 1):

Think about next script:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
echo(
set "_x=12"
set "_var=(_x)"
set "_var=!_var:(=%%!"
set "_var=!_var:)=%%!"
set _
echo(
     echo "     echo %%_var%%" %_var%
call echo "call echo %%%%_var%%%%" %_var%
```

and its output:

```
==> D:\bat\SO\40369895.bat

_var=%_x%
_x=12

"     echo %_var%" %_x%
"call echo %_var%" 12

==>
```

Note that `_` prefix in variable names (`_x` and `_var` instead of `x` and `var`) is not vital…